# How to specify multiple values for a range key while querying GSI in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I have a department table and a GSI having "tenant" as hash key and "dept_name" as range key. Both the fields are of String type.
I want to query on the GSI to get the departments for a tenant having dept_name in  [engineering, sales, facilities]. How do I achieve this?

I have used below code, Still not able to get the result.

```
  public List<Dept> getDepartments(String tenant,  List<String> depts) {
        Dept dept = new Dept();
        dept.tenant = tenant;
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<Dept> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>();
        Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN);
        rangeKeyCondition.withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withSS(depts));
        queryExpression.withIndexName("tenant_dept_index").withRangeKeyCondition("dept", rangeKeyCondition);
        queryExpression.withHashKeyValues(dept);
        //For GSI consistent read is always false
        queryExpression.setConsistentRead(false);
        List<Dept> items = mapper.query(Dept.class, queryExpression);
        return items;
      }
```

Thanks.